# Facebook Javascript SDK with Mobile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a working Facebook web application built with angular that uses the Javascript SDK in order to login into my app, and that works fine on desktop/laptop computers.
When I tried to login with my smartphone, it would not open the login window.
What would be the best approach to bypass it?
I was thinking about using the manual login flow with OAuth and then pass the user token from the server to the client in order for it to make the regular calls.
Would that be a good strategy?
If so, does it makes sense to set a user token in the Javascript SDK so I can use it?
(e.g, `FB.ui()`, `FB.api()` calls)

Comment: hard to say what´s wrong without your code, but you can read this: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: When using `FB.login()` on mobile, it must be after a user click event?

Comment: it ALWAYS must be on user interaction. you should not try to open any dialog without user interaction.

Comment: @luschn You were right, it solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @bks i am having the same issue. how did you solved it?

I execute fb.Login when user clicks a button. Still not working for me.

Comment: @GautamKrishnaR I have, just did what luschn wrote